# MongoDB Index Search

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am executing below query

```
db.collection.explain().find({
  "$and": [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          "document.attr1": {
            "$regex": "^searchValue_1$",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "document.arrayElement": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "docInsideArray": "^searchValue_1$"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "document.isActive": true
    }
  ]
})
```

and my document inside collection is having below schema

```
{
   document:{
      "attr1":"my_Document_1",
      "isActive":"Y",
      "arrayElement":[
         {
            docInsideArray:"myDocumentValue"
         },
         {
            docInsideArray:"myDocumentValue_1"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and I have following index

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "document.arrayElement.docInsideArray": 1 } )
```

When i execute the mentioned find() with explain(), it is performing collection scan instead of index scan. Please suggest for the above mentioned find() any other index is suitable?

Comment: Regex index usage is limited and even usually ineffective for case insensitive queries. [Check the docs section about this.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)